# Rabbinic sources on (un)fulfillment of prophecy in Ezekiel 29

Tags: nevua-prophecy, ezekiel--the-book

In Ezekiel 29, the prophet predicts very specifically that Nebuchadnezzar will conquer Egypt and get lots of loot. Historically, Nebuchadnezzar attempted to conquer Egypt, but was repelled by Pharaoh Amasis and died soon after. Thus Ezekiel's prophecy remains unfulfilled. (There are other prophecies in the book which also seem unfulfilled, but they are vaguer. This one is very clear-cut.)

I am wondering about the Rabbinic attitude to this fact. Does anyone know of a source where this is discussed?

Thanks!